# What happens to the frac bits when the floating point number is a sub-normal number?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding-error

I'm converting a floating point number to bits. For simplicity's sake, let's say there's 4 exponent bits and 4 frac bits. Let's say the value of frac bits is 1/4, so 0100. And say the value e is -9, so the exponent is -2 (e + bias). Now, I can't represent -2 in 4 bits so I would make the exponent bits all 0. I've now got (0 0000 0100), but obviously that's not right. What do I do from this point?

Comment: Why can't you represent -2 in 4 bits? It can represent -8 to 7.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number

Comment: Basically, you increment the exponent by enough to get into the representable range, and shift the fraction to the right as many bits as you incremented the exponent.

Comment: @Barmar In unsigned? I don't see how

Comment: By using an offset, so that an exponent `0` to `15` represents `-8` to `7`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, now I see you're talking about the signed exponent -9 after converting to unsigned.

Comment: Normally the fraction has no leading zero bits until you denormalize it. How are you starting with `0100`?

Comment: @Barmar Ah. So if the exponent is -7 (e = -14), would I increment the exponent by 7? And the frac bits wouldn't be affected (apart from the leading 1 being ignored)?

Comment: Well the value has 1+1/4 (1 + M), so the mantissa is 1/4. And that in binary is 0100 right? (0.0100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you increment the exponent from `-2` to `0`, you shift the fraction to the right by 2 bits -- the number of its is the difference between zero and the unrepresentable exponent. So the fraction becomes `0001`, and the full floating point number is

```
0 0000 0001
```

Comment: So that means it is NaN?

Comment: No, I think it just underflows to 0.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm still a bit as to how the original frac (0100) turned into 0000. Can you please elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: I miscounted, it should be `0001`